# How to permanently remove obsolete icon from Ubuntu Xfce notification tray?

Tags: desktop-environment, xfce, startup

Since I uninstalled *blueman*, the obsolete icon persists in my Xfce (Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit) notification tray with a placeholder.  There is a way to hide but not to remove it.  Can you show me how to remove it for good?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you RIGHT click it? Do you have the option to "Remove"?

Comment: No, the application menu come up, as if it were still working, but nothing actually works when selected - it is a partially broken or removed app as rozcietrzewiacz suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously I tried to Completely Uninstall in Synaptic but since I had already standard-uninstalled it, the Complete Uninstall option was a deadlink and Synaptic would not allow me to follow through with a Complete Uninstall.  I found I had to reinstall Blueman and then this time, being sure to Completely remove it in Synaptic, I was able to clear the list of known apps in Notification Area > Properties.  A reboot may have helped.

Hopefully it doesn't come back and hopefully no residual traces of it are left on my Notification tray or anywhere else on my system.  Programmers should be more mindful.

This is why I like Windows, uninstall binaries are thorough versus non-existent in Linux for many apps.  In this case Synaptic could reverse, but many apps aren't catalogued in Synaptic making it impossible to cleanly reverse messy installs.

Answer (score 1):

This must come from some program that is at least partially removed or broken. You should go to Xfce "Session & Startup" settings, scroll through the auto-started applications' list, find the no longer used program(s) and un-tick it(them) or entirely remove from the list.

Comment: The remove button is greyed out, any ideas?  I can uncheck the application but I want to remove it permanently as it has been uninstalled and I don't want dead links to it anywhere...

Comment: Have you logged out after un-checking the application? It may be not permitted(possible) to delete before you log out and back in.